# Why is my html, JS Test not working?

Tags: javascript, html

We got this code from teacher so we can learn from it. Simply, it is 10 question test with 3 possible answers on each question. If you hit number of good answers button it should give you back actual number of good answers.  I can not make this run under up to date Chrome, IE etc. Everytime I hit number of good answers button on the bottom i get nothing or zero. Only browser that will actually run it is PSPad's super old IE.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test HTML</title>


<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
var contents = true;

function counter(form)   
   {     
    var equal=0;
    if (form.o1[2].status==true)  equal++      
    if (form.o2[0].status==true)  equal++      
    if (form.o3[1].status==true)  equal++      
    if (form.o4[0].status==true)  equal++ 
    if (form.o5[0].status==true)  equal++
    if (form.o6[1].status==true)  equal++
    if (form.o7[0].status==true)  equal++
    if (form.o8[1].status==true)  equal++
    if (form.o9[0].status==true)  equal++
  if (form.o10[2].status==true)  equal++
     {
      form.right.value=" "+equal;
     }
   }
</SCRIPT>



<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
</head>
<DIV align=center>
<H3><B>TEST<br>HTML</B></H3>
<HR width="90%" color=#ffff00>
</DIV>
<FORM name=test method=post>
<TABLE width="100%" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI>q1</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o1> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=B name=o1> Answer1
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=C name=o1> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>                        

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=2>q2</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o2> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=B name=o2> Answer1
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=C name=o2> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=3>q3</LI></OL> 
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o3> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=B name=o3> Answer1 
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=C name=o3> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=4>q4</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o4> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=B name=o4> Answer1
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=C name=o4> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=5>q5</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o5> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o5> Answer1
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o5> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=6>q6</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o6> Answer0 
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o6> Answer1    
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o6> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=7>q7</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o7> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o7> Answer1   
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o7> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=8>q8</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o8> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o8> Answer1    
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o8> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=9>q9</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o9> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o9> Answer1  
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o9> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR vAlign=top><TD width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=10>q10</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o10> Answer0
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o10> Answer1 
               <br><INPUT type=radio value=A name=o10> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
<HR width="90%" color=#ffff00>
<P align=center>
<INPUT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma" onclick="return counter(this.form)" type=button value="Number of good answers"> 
<INPUT size=5 name=right> 
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thank you for solving my problem. I am not that good in JS.

EDIT: Thank you guys you are really the best. :)

Comment: Did you learn the old school upper-case code from your teacher, too?

Comment: I think he is saying he got it from his teacher =/ scary

Comment: Please beside commenting my teacher's code can you solve this code. I am really desperate. I am not proud of my teacher either.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that your teacher hasn't changed his/her notes in a long time. Thankfully it seems you are aware that the majority of what they are telling you is likely very outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the script is checking the `status` property of the input. This property was only ever supported in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

In your teachers code, `status==true` looks like it is no longer supported and returns an undefined value. You should change your Javascript function to the following:

```
function counter(form){     
    var equal=0;
    if (form.o1[2].checked==true){equal++;}
    if (form.o2[0].checked==true){equal++;}
    if (form.o3[1].checked==true){equal++;}
    if (form.o4[0].checked==true){equal++;}
    if (form.o5[0].checked==true){equal++;}
    if (form.o6[1].checked==true){equal++;}
    if (form.o7[0].checked==true){equal++;}
    if (form.o8[1].checked==true){equal++;}
    if (form.o9[0].checked==true){equal++;}
  if (form.o10[2].checked==true){
    equal++;
    form.right.value=" "+equal;
    }
}
```

`.checked` will return the boolean status that you are looking for appropriately. Also, your teachers code is formatted TERRIBLY. I'm not even certain just changing to `.checked` would work without the proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using html correct format ... I mad one question for you follow it and change other answer attributes

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test HTML</title>


<SCRIPT >
var contents = true;

function counter(form)   
{     
var equal=0;
if (form.o1[2].status==true)  equal++      
if (form.o2[0].status==true)  equal++      
if (form.o3[1].status==true)  equal++      
if (form.o4[0].status==true)  equal++ 
if (form.o5[0].status==true)  equal++
if (form.o6[1].status==true)  equal++
if (form.o7[0].status==true)  equal++
if (form.o8[1].status==true)  equal++
if (form.o9[0].status==true)  equal++
if (form.o10[2].status==true)  equal++
 {
  form.right.value=" "+equal;
 }
}
</SCRIPT>




</head>
<body>
<DIV align="center">
<H3><B>TEST<br>HTML</B></H3>
<HR width="90%" color=#ffff00>
</DIV>
<FORM name="test" method="post">
<TABLE width="100%" border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR vAlign="top"><TD width="70%">
           <OL>
           <LI>q1</LI></OL>
           <BLOCKQUOTE>
           <br><INPUT type="radio" value="A" name="o1"> Answer0

           </BLOCKQUOTE>                        

<TR ><TD width="70%">
           <OL>
           <LI value=2>q2</LI></OL>
           <BLOCKQUOTE>

           </BLOCKQUOTE>

<TR ><TD width="70%">
           <OL>
           <LI value=3>q3</LI></OL> 
           <BLOCKQUOTE>

           </BLOCKQUOTE>


 </TBODY>
 </TABLE>
 <HR width="90%" color=#ffff00>
  <P align=center>
 <INPUT style="FONT-SIZE: 8pt; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma" onclick="return counter(this)"     type=button value="Number of good answers"> 
 <INPUT size=5 name=right> 
</FORM>
 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Use proper "" where neaded...

Answer (score 0):

There are many error in your code : 
1. status to checked 
2. code does not contain semi-colon (;) at many appropriate places.
3. the tags in HTML are generic and not custom. So use Standard HTML tag.

The entire code should be : -

```
<html>
<head>
 <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">   
<title>Test hTML</title>


<script language=JavaScript type="text/javaScript">
var contents = true;

function counter(form)   
   {  
    var equal=0;
    if (form.o1[2].checked==true)  equal++;      
    if (form.o2[0].checked==true)  equal++;     
    if (form.o3[1].checked==true)  equal++;     
    if (form.o4[0].checked==true)  equal++;
    if (form.o5[0].checked==true)  equal++;
    if (form.o6[1].checked==true)  equal++;
    if (form.o7[0].checked==true)  equal++;
    if (form.o8[1].checked==true)  equal++;
    if (form.o9[0].checked==true)  equal++;
    if (form.o10[2].checked==true) equal++;
      alert(form.right.value=" "+equal);
      form.right.value=" "+equal;
   }
</script>




</head>
<body>
<div align=center>
<h3><B>TEST<br>HTML</B></h3>
<HR width="90%" color=#ffff00>
</div>
<form name=test method=post>
<table width="100%" border=0>
<tbbody>
<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI>q1</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o1> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=B name=o1> Answer1
               <br><input type=radio value=C name=o1> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>                        

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=2>q2</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o2> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=B name=o2> Answer1
               <br><input type=radio value=C name=o2> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=3>q3</LI></OL> 
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o3> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=B name=o3> Answer1 
               <br><input type=radio value=C name=o3> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=4>q4</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o4> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=B name=o4> Answer1
               <br><input type=radio value=C name=o4> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=5>q5</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o5> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o5> Answer1
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o5> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=6>q6</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o6> Answer0 
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o6> Answer1    
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o6> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=7>q7</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o7> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o7> Answer1   
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o7> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=8>q8</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o8> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o8> Answer1    
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o8> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=9>q9</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o9> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o9> Answer1  
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o9> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>

<tr vAlign=top><td width="70%">
               <OL>
               <LI value=10>q10</LI></OL>
               <BLOCKQUOTE>
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o10> Answer0
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o10> Answer1 
               <br><input type=radio value=A name=o10> Answer2
               </BLOCKQUOTE>
</tbody>
</table>
<HR width="90%" color=#ffff00>
<p align=center>
<input style="font-size:8pt; font-family:Tahoma" onclick="return counter(this.form);" type=button value="Number of good answers"> 
<input  value="" name=right> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```